# Macro for sequence

Tags: macros, sas, sequence

Hey I'm trying to learn SAS at the moment and I'm trying to write a simple macro.
The macro is supposed to print the sequence between two numbers to the log.
For example %seq(1,4) leads to

1

2

3

4

beeing printed. Unfortunately I don't really have a clue how to do this and don't find anything online. Anybody has an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this, here is one:

```
%macro seq(x,y);
%do %until (&x>&y);
  %put &x;
  %let x=%eval(&x+1);
%end;
%mend;

%seq(1,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you want to do here. If you just want to generate a series of numbers there as no need for a macro as a a data step the DO statement can do that very easily.

```
data _null_;
  do seq=1 to 4 ;
     put seq= ;
  end;
run;
```

To make it more flexible you could replace the constants `1` and the `4` with macro variables.

```
%let start=1;
%let end=4;
data _null_;
  do seq=&start to &end ;
     put seq= ;
  end;
run;
```

To make it more reusable you could wrap that into a macro.

```
%macro seq(start,end);
data _null_;
  do seq=&start to &end ;
     put seq= ;
  end;
run;
%mend seq ;
%seq(1,4)
```

You could even use the macro %DO loop instead if that data step DO loop you do not need to generate actual SAS code for this in the macro.

```
%macro seq(start,end);
%local seq;
  %do seq=&start %to &end ;
     %put seq= &seq;
  %end;
%mend seq ;
%seq(1,4)
```